Incremental blockquotes in revealjs Quarto
I would like to create multiple blockquotes incremental in a revealjs Quarto presentation. Unfortunately when using ::: {.incremental} does work when using > blockquotes. Here is some reproducible code:
---
format: revealjs
---

# Example slide

::: {.incremental}

> Tekst 1

> Tekst 2

:::

Output:

As we can see this doesn't return an incremental list of the blockquotes. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to perform this?

As @Shafee already pointed out here .incremental works on lists not other elements like callout-block, tables or blockquotes.
Instead you can use .fragments:
---
format: revealjs
---

# Example slide

::: {.fragment}

> Tekst 1

:::

::: {.fragment}

> Tekst 2

:::

